# Azure Ghost Unable to Unlink sqlite3

Tags: git, azure, sqlite, azure-web-app-service, ghost-blog

I've got a Azure Website running Ghost with a git repository in the site itself.

On my local machine, I make a simple change to a file, (.gitignore in this case), and push to the server.

Here's the error I get.

> error: unable to unlink old
>   'node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v11-win32-ia32/node_sqlite3.node'
>   (Permission denied)

I've been able to determine that this is because there still something hanging on to sqlite and it can't release it. If I stop the site and restart it, as long as nobody has hit the site, I can retry the deployment and it goes through just fine.

The deployment log has this:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling node.js deployment.
Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.17, 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.12.0.
Selected node.js version 0.10.32. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
 > sqlite3@3.0.2 install D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
 [sqlite3] Success: "D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v11-win32-ia32\node_sqlite3.node" is installed via remote
sqlite3@3.0.2 node_modules\sqlite3
└── nan@1.3.0
Finished successfully.
```

Okay. So is there anyway to push and deploy without it attempting to do something with sqlite and without having to shut down the site and restart it?

Comment: Is this related to updating ghost, or just your content?

Comment: I wasn't updating ghost, the engine. At least, not explicitly. My main goal is to be able to push changes to my theme's code.